# Couldn't login to Google account

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to automate the login of a Google account shows:

> "Couldn't sign you in, the browser or app may not be secure".

I enabled the "allow less secure apps" -option in Google security settings but that didn't solve it. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
googlesheet = 'google address'

driver.get(googlesheet) 
time.sleep(2)

# login
login = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
login.send_keys('')

next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/span/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
password.send_keys('')

sign = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/span').click()
```